# How to add a NOT NULLABLE column with a foreign key to an existing table that already contains data?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

An example for this problem:

> Imagine you have a table projects. The table projects already 
>   contains data. Now you want to add a project_type_id column to the 
>   table, that can't be NULL and has a foreign key to the project_types 
>   table.
>
> The database sees the project_type_id can't be NULL, so it inserts a 
>   0 in the column for all the existing rows. The 0 does not exist in 
>   the project_types table, so the foreign key constraint fails. This 
>   means you can't add the foreign key.

I thought about adding a first "default" row to the project_types table and link all the projects to that type. This isn't a good solution, because the user has to change all the types from "default" to the correct type.

What is your solution for this problem?

Comment: The whole point of FKs is to enforce integrity. Don't search for workarounds, but instead make sure the data is correct. So, before adding your FK, make sure that column has valid data.

Comment: Either that or set it to nullable while not all data is added. Unknown / null seems like a valid option in your case.

Comment: I think I will use the method @jeroen suggested. In the backend we will make the field required and everytime someone makes a change to a project, he needs to choose a project type until all the data is filled in correctly. Then we can add the NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this issue is:

> 1. Create a new migration in order to add **project_type_id** column to projects table:

```
php artisan make:migration add_project_type_column_to_projects_table --table=projects

 public function up()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer("project_type_id")->unsigned();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn("project_type_id");
    });
}
```

***It's going to add 0 value as default in each column but no problem because it's not foreign key yet.***

> 2.Define the relationship between Project and ProjectType models

```
//Your Project class

class Project extends Model
{
 protected $fillable=["your columns..."];

 public function type()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectType::class);
  }
}


//Your ProjectType class

class ProjectType extends Model
{
  protected $fillable=["Your columns..."];

  public function projects()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
  }
}
```

> 3. Now you must go and set the correct values for **project_type_id** either manually or from your admin panel.
> 4. Now your column is ready to be set as foreign key, so go ahead and make a new migration to set the **project_type_id** as foreign key.

```
php artisan make:migration set_project_type_id_column_as_foreign_key --table=projects

public function up()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign("project_type_id")
            ->references("id")
            ->on("project_types")
            ->onDelete("cascade")//is up to you
            ->onUpdate("cascade");// is up to you
    });
}
 public function down()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign("projects_project_type_id_foreign"); //This one could be different
    });
}
```

***Now your table has a new (NOT NULLABLE) foreign key with correct values.***

Answer (score 0):

You should have a valid foreign key that exists in DB, for example: `1`

Then Create a new migration :

```
$table->integer('project_type_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
$table->foreignkey('project_type_id')->references('id')->on('project_types');
```

Then user has to manually change every one of them or change them randomly (random valid ids) with `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

I think one workaround here would be to first add the new column *without* a foreign key reference.  Then update the values of that column, and afterwards add the foreign key constraint.  Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE projects ADD COLUMN project_type_id INT;

-- now update with correct values

ALTER TABLE projects ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pt_id FOREIGN KEY (project_type_id)
REFERENCES yourTable(parent_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deploy to different environments, you could add a default value to the project_type_id (as @Ahmad Mobaraki suggested). Of course, you must have that value in the project_type table.

Then, create an Artisan command that fetches all rows and that updates the project_type_id to the right value, according to your business logic.

Finally, after running the migration, run that Artisan custom command.

At this point, you have a non-nullable foreign key with the right values.

I had the same issue (yes, I know, 2019) and solved that way. After deployment in other environments, just run the update script.

I use to create Artisan commands that are run manually after the automated deployment. Most of the time, automated deployments are just fine, but when there are some tasks like this, the best solution I have found is to have a custom Artisan command that handles that extra work.

Other solution I have explored in the past is to handle that updating in the same migration file, but that mixes things up. Database structure and data, and, on top of that, it assumes the database has data. With this approach, even when it is not fully automated, you have a clear separation between structure and data.